# iOS Swift - UIImageView can't set ContentMode

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cifilter, contentmode

I'm using a CIFilter to add a filter to an image. The resulted image after filtering the image has this size: `CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 70)`. I can't set the resulted image content mode to `ScaleAspectFill`. Here is the code:

```
    filter2image.frame = CGRectMake(90, 10, 70, 70)
    let filter2data = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectChrome")
    filter2data.setValue(CIImage(image: imageView.image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    self.filter2image.image = UIImage(CIImage: filter2data.outputImage)
    filter2image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't set ContentMode? Is there an error or is the result not what you expect?  If so, how?

Comment: @BryanCimo - this is the result after applying contentMode ScaleAspectFill. https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-9/11117244_1428954010747557_1185009472806635556_n.jpg?oh=a4c669524e90bcc237cb548e719361ea&oe=5609D752&__gda__=1438585139_80f23d9206edf1035790c69b30cee011

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the frame after you set the contentMode. Like this:

```
let filter2data = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectChrome")
filter2data.setValue(CIImage(image: imageView.image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
self.filter2image.image = UIImage(CIImage: filter2data.outputImage)
filter2image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
filter2image.frame = CGRectMake(90, 10, 70, 70)
```

Comment: Have you tried setNeedsDisplay? That will notify the system that your view's content's need to be redrawn.